# Json Deserialize with multiple value

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net, json.net

These the data what i get

```
{
  "s": "ok",
  "t": [
    1509469200,
    1509469500,
    1509469800,
    1509470100,
    1509470400,
    1509470700,
    1509471000
  ],
  "r": [
    6040100,
    5955000,
    5955000,
    5999600,
    5999400,
    5999000,
    5960100
  ],
  "v": [
    3.06575198,
    7.92733913,
    6.04823174,
    0.87041449,
    0.27879491,
    0.31525724,
    0.08880846
  ]
}
```

I can get s value with this code and it return "ok".

```
Dim pData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response_)
Dim status As String = pData("s")
```

But i got error for other values, How to get t, r, s, v as array or list of string from this json?

```
Dim time_ As List(Of String) = pData("t")

Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.
```

Comment: `But i got error for other values` care to share what that error was and what exactly you tried?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Create a class with properties that json can deserialize to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class

```
Public Class JSON_result
    Public Property s As String
    Public Property t As Integer()
    Public Property r As Integer()
    Public Property v As Double()
End Class
```

then deserialize the json to object of that class.

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_result)(response_jsonString)
```

Now you can access properties as,

`obj.s`
and array elements as
`obj.t(0)`
`obj.r(0)`
`obj.v(0)`

Comment: NOTE for other visitors: you must import library
`Imports Newtonsoft.Json`